# Images won't shrink when thumbnail area is pressed in an imageview

Tags: android, imageview

I'm trying to implement an imageview where users can press on a thumbnail and have the image expand and then press on that same image again and have the image shrink back to a thumbnail.

The problem I'm having is that after the image has expanded if the user presses on the area over where the original thumbnail was, it just refreshes the expanded image instead of shrinking it, the user has to press on a part of the screen that doesn't cover the original thumbnail in order to shrink it back down again.

Is there some kind of property that I need to change in the xml to fix this or is it related to my java code?

Comment: You should add a boolean to the activity to see in the OnClick whether it's already expanded or not. Right now it most likely just performs your first OnClick method over and over instead of shrinking it. You can create two methods, like expand(View v) and shrink(View v), linking each to the appropriate clickables.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a condition for the thumbnail button so it won't do the same thing twice.
ex:

```
boolean thumbnailClicked = false;
...
@Override onClick(View v) {
    if(thumbnailClicked){
        //code to decrease image size here
        thumbnailClicked = false;
    }
    else {
        //code to increase image size here
        thumbnailClicked = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried setting it up like that but it still exhibits the same behaviour, it's as if the view is being pressed twice.

Comment: Do you also have an android:onClick="" in your xml for the button? That might be the cause for a double click.